# Padauk Mini-c programming language

Tags: microcontroller, c, programming

I want to program Padauk PMS171B ic using [Padauk tech emulator and IDE](http://www.padauk.com.tw/en/technical/index.aspx?kind=26). For this I wish to use mini-c but I don't find any related documents of mini-c. Is there any mini-c documents or example codes written in mini-c for different Padauk ICs?

Comment: do you mean [this](https://free-pdk.github.io/)? Because the SDCC that comes with that actually compiles standard C.

Comment: if that's not what you mean, please link to the software you're planning on using! Padauk's "IDE" page only shows in-circuit programmer *hardware* and not a single link to a compiler, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Skimming through an archive's binary content that I got from a product page... there seems to be documentation, but it's all in Chinese!

Comment: I want to use 5S-I-S02/B emulator provided by Padauk using their IDE. This ide supports either asm or mini-c. I need to know about the difference in syntax between this mini-c and standard c.

Comment: can you link to the IDE? I really can't find it, but as I said, I found *something* containing lots of examples and documentation in Chinese, which I can't read.

Comment: [Link](http://www.padauk.com.tw/en/technical/index.aspx?kind=26)
Here are IDEs and its manual documentation. I want to use 5S-I-S02/B emulator

Comment: I have [edit]ed our question to add the link where is belongs. Please do this the next time, comments are not for adding new information. This is not a forum.

Comment: Did you try to ask Padauk?